# Conditional expectation on exponential distribution

Tags: expected-value, conditional-expectation

How can I compute the conditional expectation C-X in the following formula

E[C-X|X$<$C];

where C is a constant and X a random variable following exponential distribution?

Comment: Have you tried writing the expression as an integral and solving that?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $X \sim \mathcal{E}(\lambda)$, then we have

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[C-X \mid X < C] &= \frac{\mathbb{E}[ (C-X)I_{X<C}]}{P(X<C)} \\
&= \frac{CP(X<C) - \mathbb{E}[XI_{X<C}]}{P(X<C)} \\
&= C - \frac{\mathbb{E}[XI_{X<C}]}{1- e^{-\lambda C}}
\end{align*}

Where $I_{\cdot}$ is the indicator function.

Now we need to solve the expectation which is basic integration

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[XI_{X<C}] &= \int_0^C \lambda x e^{-\lambda x} dx \\
&= \frac{1}{\lambda} - e^{-\lambda C}(C + \frac{1}{\lambda} )
\end{align*}

Thus we finally have

$$
\mathbb{E}[C-X \mid X < C] = C + \frac{ e^{-\lambda C}(C + \frac{1}{\lambda} ) - \frac{1}{\lambda}}{1 - e^{-\lambda C}}
$$

Here is a little R code to check if it works with $\lambda = 0.01$ and $C=45$

```
Ck<-45
X<-rexp(1e7,0.01)
Y<-X[X<Ck]   ## Select only the values of X < Ck
mean(Ck-Y)   ## empirical expectation 
Ck + (Ck*exp(-0.01*Ck) + (exp(-0.01*Ck)-1)/0.01)/(1-exp(-0.01*Ck))
```

More generally when you have an conditional expectation of the type

$$
\mathbb{E}[X \mid A]
$$

you can use the relation

$$
\mathbb{E}[X \mid A] = \frac{\mathbb{E}[X I_A]}{P(A)}
$$

Comment: Thank you @winperikle. I had done the sam job but  my result is  a bit different. In your last equation, in the numerator, it should be $\e^{-\lambda.C}$ (C+1/$\lambda$) I guess, no ? My solution differs from there